# VB.NET Inheritance Pattern with Auto Complete Members

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, design-patterns

I have scoured the web looking for a way to create a class and have it auto populate itself with member functions, much like the way IDisposable does when you press enter after implementing it.

I know I can design my own interfaces, but all member subs, properties and functions get auto populated with 'Throw New Not NotImplementedException()'.

Is there a way these can refer to the 'Base' class as default? eg. MyBase.Sub(), or populate with code that I choose?

Comment: That functionality for `IDisposable` is built into the IDE.  You'd have to write your own VS extension to do what you want.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for the reply. So the IDE has thousands of macros to generate those lines of code?This is also what others have mentioned, I just didn't believe it, I assumed there was some XML or other trickery to achieve the result. At least now I can stop obsessing.